Left outer-join sqlalchemy ORM -> get one object as result
I'm looking to replicate a SQL query I've been using in pgAdmin to join multiple tables and download the resulting table into a CSV file. I've been successful with pgAdmin and want to achieve the same result using SQLAlchemy, as my application interacts with the database through SQLAlchemy.
In pgAdmin, I use a query like this:
SELECT * FROM visits
LEFT JOIN patients ON visits.patient_id = patients.patient_id
LEFT JOIN [many more left joins here]
WHERE visits.visit_id = 1;

To accomplish the same using SQLAlchemy, I attempted the following code:
def get_all_data_for_visit(self, visit_id: int):
    try:
        stmt = select(Visit, Patient).outerjoin(Patient, and_(Visit.patient_id == Patient.patient_id, Visit.visit_id == visit_id))
        result = self.db.execute(stmt).all()
        if result:
            for row in result:
                print(row.Patient.patient_id, row.Visit.visit_type)
            return result
        else:
            return None
    except OperationalError as e:
        self.show_error_msg()

However, this code returns a patients object and a visits object, which is not the desired outcome. I want to iterate over the objects and print all their attributes (e.g., row.Visit.visit_type) into the CSV. I can't simply iterate over all existing objects because some might be None, but I still want the results (null in this case) in the table. With my SQL-query this works. With sqlalchemy I get an AttributeError.
I read related questions, but I could not find a solution to my specific question.
Thank you for your help!

You need to list all the tables in the select() argument list. If you only list Visit and Patient, it's like writing SELECT visits.*, patients.* instead of SELECT *.

Visit.visit_id == visit_id shouldn't be in the outerJoin() condition.

@Barmar : I first tried with only Patient and Visit, that's why I have only Visit and Patient in select. My problem is, that I get back a patient-Object and a visit-Object. But I want one object where all attributes (of patient and visit) are combined (null if none-existent). Where should I put Visit.visit_id == visit_id ?

I don't use SQLAlchemy, but I don't think that's how it works in general. Every table corresponds to its own class so you get instances of that class. What class would your desired result be?

SQLAlchemy's ORM layer returns tuples of objects in join results because, in general, programmers are using the ORM because it is convenient to work with graphs of objects rather than flat arrays of row data. In the case in the question - writing join query results direct to a report - working with a flat array is more convenient. The solution is to use SQLAlchemy's core layer instead of the ORM, which will behave like regular SQL.
The core layer works with tables rather than ORM entities. Given that the ORM entity classes exist the tables can be obtained from them:
patients = Patient.__table__
visits = Visit.__table__

The query statement is almost identical, save that columns are accessed via the tables' .c (or .columns) attribute rather than directly:
q = stmt = (
    sa.select(Patient, Visit)
    .outerjoin(Patient, Visit.patient_id == Patient.patient_id)
    .where(Visit.visit_id == visit_id)
)

To replicate the SQL in the question I have switched the order of the tables in the projection and, as Barmar implied, moved the visit_id filter from the join condition into a WHERE clause. The query can be executed by a session or connection.
The result of the execution will be a CursorResult instance, which you can think of as an iterable of namedtuples. Individual columns in a row can be accessed by name or position.
Note that SQLAlchemy will automatically disambiguate identifiers that appear multiple times in the results columns. You can see the column names in the result by calling the CursorResult's .keys() method.
